# Typescript function arguments based on types with enums as keys

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Lets say that I have an enum with a set of action types:

```
export enum ActionTypes {
  action1 = 'action1',
  action2 = 'action2',
  action3 = 'action3',
  // ...etc
}
```

And I have a set of payload types that a function wants when performing that action, which is keyed off the action types themselves:

```
export type ActionPayloads = {
  [ActionTypes.action1]: boolean,
  [ActionTypes.action2]: string,
  [ActionTypes.action3]: void,
  // ...etc
}
```

I want to use a function that takes as its first parameter the action type from the enum, and then use TS hinting to have it infer the payload type for argument two:

```
function exampleFn<T extends ActionTypes, U extends ActionPayloads[T]> (type: T, data?: U): void {
  //...
}
```

I feel like this would work, but even if I change ActionPayloads to an interface, in both cases for `U extends ActionPayloads[T]` I get the error `TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'ActionPayloads'`

Am I missing something here? I feel like this should work, given that there's nothing fancy going on with the usage of the enum.

Comment: Is your `type ActionPayloads` valid?

Comment: It was a typo - I copied it by hand, because I was trying to simpliify it. Fixed it.
@zerkms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** to reproduce the error

The error can be reproduced by omitting any possibility of `ActionTypes` from `ActionPayloads`.

```js
export enum ActionTypes {
  action1 = "action1",
  action2 = "action2",
  action3 = "action3",
  // ...etc
}

export type ActionPayloads = {
  [ActionTypes.action1]: boolean;
  // [ActionTypes.action2]: string; // accidentally omit action2
  [ActionTypes.action3]: void;
  // ...etc
}

function exampleFn<T extends ActionTypes, U extends ActionPayloads[T]>(type: T, data?: U): void {

}
```

Since `exampleFn` takes all possibilities of `ActionTypes` as `T`, `U` expands `ActionPayloads[T]` with such. If any possibility of `T` is omitted in `ActionPayloads`, `T` cannot be used to index `ActionPayloads`. That's what the error message tells.

Comment: @zerkms no, his type was not valid.

Comment: That was actually a typo (since I've been going back and forth between the interface and type definition I left out the `=`). I still get the error. Any other idea?

Comment: Updated to what it actually was. Sorry, I copied it by hand so I could simplify it.

Comment: What error do you get now? Can you post more details?

Comment: It's the same error. I had typed in my example incorrectly

Comment: @TimTime Wong what version of typescript are you on? I'm on 3.4.5

Comment: What's weird is, I'm getting intellisense errors but the method works fine, types are properly detected. I wonder if it's an issue with my IDE (Intellij)

Comment: Tested with various versions in TypeScript Playground. That's why I asked for the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. My enum, which is quite a bit larger than the example, had one entry that was not accounted for in the payload type.

This entire thing was caused by a mismatch; it works fine.

Long story short, the error message does not really provide information of use, and make sure that your keys from both enum and type line up. Huge waste of time here.